# R nested function call

Tags: r, function

I came across this R code,

```
f <- function(x) {
     g <- function(y) {
         y + z
     }
     z <- 4
     x + g(x)
}
```

I cannot seem to understand what the answer would be if it were run with the following parameters

```
z <- 10
f(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down. The function:

```
f <- function(x) {
   g <- function(y) {
       y + z
   }
   z <- 4
   x + g(x)
}
```

Contains the function `g`. This function isn't called until the last line, so it won't try to access any variables until that point. We can therefore safely replace it with an identical anonymous function at the point it is called:

```
f <- function(x) {
     z <- 4
     x + (function(y){y + z})(y = x)
}
```

Now we can clearly see that the `z` that is assigned in the first line of our function is going to be used in the last line, and that means the `z` we declared globally is going to be ignored, so we can further simplify:

```
f <- function(x) {
     x + (function(y){y + 4})(y = x)
}
```

So how do we work out what this gives us? Well, calling the function `function(y){y + 4}` with `(y = x)` is the same as evaluating `{x + 4}`, so our function becomes:

```
f <- function(x) {
     x + ({x + 4})
}
```

Which could be further simplified to

```
f <- function(x) 2 * x + 4
```

You can see that we have removed the symbols `g`, `y` and `z` from the function without changing its output. Furthermore, we can see that it doesn't matter what you assign to `z` in the global environment, because it is never used in the function.

With any of the functions above, since they are all logically equivalent, you get the same output. That is, whatever number you call the function with, it is doubled and four is added.

```
f(3)
#> [1] 10
```

Answer (score 2):

g is a function, and will not be executed until it is called. When you call g with g(x), z = 4 at that time.

For x = 3;

x + g(x) = 3 + g(3) = 3 + (3 + 4) = 10